# Can't use sugar.js functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, sugar.js

I tried to use [sugar](https://sugarjs.com/docs/#/Array/compact). Previously I used it one year ago and it worked good in such way:

```
> npm install sugar
test@1.0.0 D:\work\test\test
`-- sugar@2.0.4
> node
>> require('sugar');
{ [Function: Sugar]
.....
 Array:
   { [Function: SugarChainable]
   .....
   compact: [Function: compact],
....
>> [1,null,2,undefined,3].compact()

TypeError: [1,null,2,undefined,3].compact is not a function
    at repl:1:24
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:23:33)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:339:29)
    at bound (domain.js:280:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:293:12)
    at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:536:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:241:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:590:8)
```

Any ideas what is wrong now?

Comment: Please update your answer to explain what you're trying to do and what is happening instead.

Comment: to use sugar function you first need to create a sugar instance of array like: `var _sugar = new Sugar.Array([1,2])` and then you can use the sugar array function on `_sugar`

Comment: see this: https://runkit.com/raghavgarg1257/59bed7c1f69b95001109ab7f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [SugarJS front page](https://sugarjs.com/):

> As of v2.0, native extension has become opt-in while supporting two new ways of interacting with the library. Sugar still believes in the safe extension of natives, however there are times when this is not appropriate, and this choice is now put in the hands of the user.

So you either need to use the chainable Sugar API:

```
var arr = new Sugar.Array([1,null,2,undefined,3]);
arr.compact();
```

This can be made into a one-liner like so:

```
(new Sugar.Array([1,null,2,undefined,3])).compact()
```

Or extend natives:

```
Sugar.extend();
```

While extending may seem simpler, there's a reason they've built it so you need to opt-in to this feature. Simply put, extending prototypes is dangerous as multiple libraries may want to extend the same prototypes and will cause collisions in their methods.

Answer (score 3):

To use these functions on native objects you need to call:

```
Sugar.extend();
```

More here: https://sugarjs.com/quickstart/